# Get value from array using integer array for location javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have two arrays, one is a multidimensional array, the other an integer array storing a location in the former to read and edit. I can read, using a separate variable, but I have no idea how to edit. Example:

```
var loc = [ 2, 4];
var groups = [
      ["Samantha", "Janice", "Lisa", "Wendell", "Laura"],
      ["Rachel", "John", "Smithy"],
      ["Mandy", "Randy", "Jamal", "Erica"]
];
```

In this example how could I edit the value in groups, at the location stored in the loc variable:

```
groups[2][4]
```

Also remember that group is not necessarily 2 dimensional all the time.

Comment: `groups[2][4]` will be `undefined`, `groups[2][3]` however will be `"Erica"`

Comment: yeah, lol, missed that. thanks

Comment: this is a plain JS question, it has nothing to do with Processing.js specifically.

Comment: not specifically but I am using Javascript with Processing.js so I wasn't sure if the method would need any processing functionality.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function edit (toBeEdited, indexes, value) {
   var array = toBeEdited,
       len = indexes.length - 1,
       i = 0,
       idx = null;

   for ( ; i < len; i += 1 ) {
      idx = indexes[i];

      if ( idx in array ) {
        array = array[idx];
      } else {
         throw new Error("index out of bounds");
      }
   }

   idx = indexes[len];
   if ( idx in array ) {
     array[idx] = value;
   } else {
     throw new Error("index out of bounds");
   }
 }

 var loc = [ 2, 3 ];
 var groups = [
       ["Samantha", "Janice", "Lisa", "Wendell", "Laura"],
       ["Rachel", "John", "Smithy"],
       ["Mandy", "Randy", "Jamal", "Erica"]
 ];

 edit(groups, loc, "Anna"); // will replace "Erica" with "Anna"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply step into the nested array until you reach your desired depth:

```
function update(data, pos, newValue) {
  pos = pos.slice();
  while(pos.length > 1) {
    data = data[pos[0]];
    pos.splice(0,1);
  }
  data[pos[0]] = newValue;
}
```

And now we can run

```
var loc = [ 2, 3 ];
var groups = [
  ["Samantha", "Janice", "Lisa", "Wendell", "Laura"],
  ["Rachel", "John", "Smithy"],
  ["Mandy", "Randy", "Jamal", "Erica"]
];
update(groups, loc, "jehosephat");
```

and then if we console log what's in `groups[2][3]` we'll see the updated value. The idea this implements is "we have a list of deeper and deeper positions, and an array of arrays of [...] with data", so we simply keep rebinding the array data until there's only one level left, which is where we'll find the value to update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this is what I figured out:

```
var edit = function(toBeEdited, indexes, value){
   var gL=value;

   var tgL;
   for (var x=0; x < indexes.length; x++){
        var n=indexes.length-1-x;

       tgL=toBeEdited;
       for (var y=0; y < n; y++){
           tgL=tgL[indexes[y]];
       }

       tgL[indexes[n]]=gL;
       gL=tgL;
   }

   return tgL;
};
```